# how to remove � sign in php while displaying content from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

**The web page shows the content as below**

> Golden Temple�is a Sikh�Gurdwara�located in the city
>   of�Amritsar,�Punjab,�India. It was built by�Guru Arjan, in the 16th
>   Century.

**but the actual content is as below**

> Golden Temple is a Sikh Gurdwara located in the city of
>   Amritsar,Punjab,India. It was built by Guru Arjan, in the 16th
>   Century.

please help me

Comment: Encoding FTW......Hint: [This](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) should help you

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details on the encoding used in your application and on the database.

Comment: Don't try to *remove* them. You need to find, why they are generated and fix it right there at the source.

Comment: i'm using utf-8 charset in and Collation of database is latin1_swedidh_ci

Comment: Don't forget to let mysql know you're communicating in UTF-8: `$connection->set_charset("UTF8");`

Comment: still it's display the same.
any other idea please...

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^\x00-\x7F]+/', '', $dbstring); // remove all non-ASCII (so called special) characters from your string:
```

or

```
$result=utf8_encode($dbstring);  // encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8
```

Comment: but i want to use multiple languages like english, urdu, arebic, hindi etc .
this is not working with other languages